# Xamarin ... migration to .NET Standard 2.0 failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to migrate my PCL project to the new "net standard" but for now I failed.

Currently I got the following exception :

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.SimpleValueTargetProvider..ctor(System.Object[], System.Object, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.INameScope)'.'
```

It happend directly from the 'InitializeComponent' of a page where I have the following xaml tag:

```
<Image Source="{ns_uc:ImageResource i_home_on.png}"/>
```

where the 'ImageResource' is an extension marker, this one works like a charm in my PCL project. Here is a part of the definition :

```
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
```

But this class is not called from my new .NET Standard project !

In the .csproj I have the following references, it should be enough ?

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="3.4.0.1008975" />
```

So, if someone have an idea because I have already spend 2 days in this migration, without success :-(

BTW, it seems I'm not alone : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101999/cant-use-imarkupextension-in-a-net-standard-library

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.System.ComponentModel is a NuGet package in some NetStandard versions.Try to install it if it doesn't exist.

2.You can use `<Image Source="myImage.png"/>` directly instead of using `IMarkupExtension` in .net standard project.

3.The implement of `ImageResourceExtension` maybe different in PCL project and .net standard 2.0 project. Here is an implement in official demo you can refer:

```
 [ContentProperty("Source")]
        class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension<ImageSource>
            {
                public string Source { set; get; }

                public ImageSource ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Source))
                    {
                        IXmlLineInfoProvider lineInfoProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXmlLineInfoProvider)) as IXmlLineInfoProvider;
                        IXmlLineInfo lineInfo = (lineInfoProvider != null) ? lineInfoProvider.XmlLineInfo : new XmlLineInfo();
                        throw new XamlParseException("ImageResourceExtension requires Source property to be set", lineInfo);
                    }

                    string assemblyName = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
                    return ImageSource.FromResource(assemblyName + "." + Source, typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                }

                object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
                {
                    return (this as IMarkupExtension<ImageSource>).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
                }
            }
```

You can refer the demo below to fix your project.

Refer:[Demo of ImageResourceExtension](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/XAML/MarkupExtensions/)

[Documents of Markup Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/creating)

Answer (score 0):

I would follow James Montemagno's steps:

https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/

I followed this video from the Xamarin show:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-15-Upgrading-to-XamarinForms-to-NET-Standard

I tried it on my own the first go around and failed miserably.  The second go around I followed the instructions from the video exactly and everything worked.